# MinGW-w32 vs. MinGW

Tags: mingw, mingw32, mingw-w64

What's the difference between the [MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/) project and the [32-bit portion](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/) of the [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) project? Does the 32-bit portion of MinGW-w64 have any relation to x64 at all?

It seems like their compilers do the exact same things...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One looks like it "cross compiles", from 64 bit to 32 bit, whereas the other looks native.

That was just a quick look though, so I could be a long long way off the mark here......

EDIT: This is only somewhat true. A better explanation is provided [here](http://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/Tip_Cross_Compiling_OpenFOAM_in_Linux_For_Windows_with_MinGW#Differences_between_mingw32_and_mingw-w32_versions)

Comment: @Ben: That's what I thought (well, 32-bit to 64-bit), but in fact when you try to compile with `-m32` in MinGW-w64, it says "sorry, 32-bit not compiled in". :(

Comment: When you build mingw, it may need to be built with the 32-bit extensions. Of course, chances are you're not building MinGW, and thus getting the stock (i.e. 64 bit). They most likely recommend using MinGW for 32 bit builds, and thus don't add in extra options (like -m32) unless you do it yourself.

Comment: @Ben: I'm confused... there's MinGW, MinGW-w32, and MinGW-w64. The last one can't cross-compile for 32-bit, and the first two can't cross-compile for 64-bit. I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but my question was whether there's a difference between the first two or not.

Comment: Hmm, you know, seems like my answer was wrong - the [FAQ](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/download%20filename%20structure) suggests that it does the exact same thing as MinGW32

Comment: @Ben: Hm... which part of the FAQ are you referring to specifically?

Comment: Actually, http://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/Tip_Cross_Compiling_OpenFOAM_in_Linux_For_Windows_with_MinGW#Differences_between_mingw32_and_mingw-w32_versions provides a better explanation! I've updated my answer to include this link.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 20):

The MinGW from http://www.mingw.org/ does only support gcc 32 bit (host and target). The independent [minGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) project provides support for 64 bit, and also supports a much larger part of the Windows API. The MinGW-w64 project however does **not** provide official binary builds: These can be grabbed either from the personal build directories of the developers (the most popular being [rubenvb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/)), or from associated but independent projects like [tdm-gcc](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) or [mingw-builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/) or [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/).

Source: http://wiki.qt.io/MinGW-64-bit

Answer (score 13):

As said by others MinGW-w64 is a fork of the original MinGW which supports both 32 and 64bit x86 processors.
You can find the original motivation for the fork here:

https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/History/

Regarding the differences you can find a list here:

https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Feature%20list/

Comment: Also, "Despite the name, MinGW-w64 **both runs on and builds binaries for** both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows, but you need to make sure you download the right package according to which platform you are running on, and which platform you want to target. " (emphasis mine) http://ascend4.org/Setting_up_a_MinGW-w64_build_environment#MinGW-w64

Answer (score 6):

There's a bit of insight into this in the [Wikipedia talk page on the MinGW article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:MinGW#mingw64_fork).  Basically, it appears that the MinGW-w64 project is a fork of the MinGW source base.  I have found very little clear information on the details of why the fork happened (although [this mailing-list post](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.mingw.devel/3386) and [this rebuttal](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.mingw.devel/3383)implies it was some form of the usual sort of open-source politics), or of the subsequent differences between the two projects.

To a first approximation, they're the same; the differences will come in in subsequent development.