# Where can I install G++/GCC for windows 8?

Tags: eclipse, gcc, mingw, mingw-w64

Newbie programmer here, I'm getting an error when using Eclipse saying
**"G++/GCC not found in path"**

So apparently I need a compiler? I need a download link to g++ since I can't find it anywhere on the web.. I went on to GNU collection's website but there is NO download link for G++,

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The usual resources would be MinGW (32-bits) or MinGW-W64 (64-bits).  Start with these links

- *[MinGW-w32 vs. MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619341/mingw-w32-vs-mingw)*
- *[MinGW — Minimalist GNU for Windows](http://mingw.org/)*
- *[MinGW-w64 - for 32 and 64 bit Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) (Since the mingw-w64 project on sourceforge.net is moving to mingw-w64.org i suggest to use [mingw-w64.org](http://mingw-w64.org))*
- *[mingw-w64 — GCC for Windows 64 & 32 bits](http://mingw-w64.yaxm.org/doku.php)*